# Ошибка mysql socket

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, lampp

Здравствуйте. Появилась такая проблема:

> [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '
>     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Погуглив, сделал, как [в этом видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXjJRrbKjp0)

Теперь у ошибки изминилось последнее число на 13

> [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '
>     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)

Кто сталкивался с этим? Как решить проблему?
Ubuntu 14.04
LAMPP

Вот, что показывает консоль:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

убедитесь, что `mysqld` действительно запущен (команда должна вернуть **одно** число — номер процесса `mysqld` в вашей системе, число 29676 — лишь пример):

```
$ pidof mysqld
29676
```

посмотрите, какие сокеты открыты этим процессом (приведён и примерный вывод команды):

```
$ sudo lsof -U -a -p 29676
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
mysqld  29676 mysql   12u  unix 0xf0bd0a00      0t0 302558 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

если команда не вернула имя сокета или имя отличается от `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`, проверьте настройки mysql в каталоге `/etc/mysql/`.

в частности, найдите, в каких файлах задаётся значение *socket*:

```
 $ grep -r '^socket.*=' /etc/mysql/
```

а затем убедитесь, что, во-первых, задаваемое значение равно `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`, а во-вторых, что оно задаётся как минимум в секции `[myslqd]` найденного конф. файла.

изменение конф. файлов, естественно, потребует перезапуска демона *mysqld*. не забудьте, что после перезапуска у процесса будет другой номер.

Comment: Проблема вот в чем, я использую LAMPP, но там возинкла проблема, PDO драйвер не работал. Выполнил комманду: `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql` после чего PDO стал работать, но появилась ошибка связанная с сокетом.

Comment: @Александр 1. с помощью программы `mysql` удаётся подключиться к *mysqld* и к используемой базе данных? 2. mysqld из оф. репозитория дистрибутива?

Comment: Добавил в пост результат выполнения этих комманд. Полагаю, что PDO пытается заюзать другой сокет, т.к. в LAMPP отсутствовал PDO (только *.dll для Windows были).

Comment: я не знаю, что такое *LAMPP*, подозреваю, что это apache+php+mysql, только собранный неизвестно кем и неизвестно что делающий.  неужели наличие dll-файлов не натолкнуло вас на мысль, что вы делаете что-то явно не то? судя по тому, что php пытается обратиться не к тому файлу, который создаёт этот ваш *LAMPP*, он черпает информацию из верного источника — каталога /etc/mysql. если такового каталога (или файла /etc/mysql*) вообще нет, я бы порекомендовал удалить этот *LAMPP* (если, конечно, получится), и установить из репозитория упомянутую связку apache+php+mysql.